# Zünden and entzünden

Tags: difference

What's the difference between *zünden* and *entzünden*?

Comment: What does the dictionary say? Is it sufficient to answer the question? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between **zünden** and **entzünden** is very subtle.

Other verbs with the prefix *ent-* mean either something misses something else: That's e.g. the case for *entgehen*, *entscheiden*, and *entsichern*.

Or they mean something is released out of something else: That's e.g. the case for *entleeren*, *entfahren*, *entrauchen*, and *entweichen*. And for *entzünden*, too.

**Entzünden** means a flame appears out of something.

> Die Decke entzündete sich an dem Heizstrahler.

*The blanket caught fire from the radiant heater.*

> Sie entzündete sein Verlangen mit einem einzigen Blick.

*She emblazed his desire with one single glance.*

Whereas **zünden** means to put a spark to something, so it does *entzünden*. It's also used instead of *entzünden* to picture the spark needed for a detonation:

> Ein einziger Funke zündete das explosive Gemisch.

*One single spark ignited the explosive mix.*

> Der Witz zündete.

*The joke sparked (the audience).*

Comment: "Entzünden" also has the side meaning of "cause inflammation" (in living tissue, also intransitive). In the context of fire, "entzünden" is more often used where an actual fire (lasting some amount of time) is the consequence (eg with candles, flammable materials). Often, "anzünden" is the clearer word - unless you need the "sich entzünden" intransitive form, which would only work for "anzünden" in a few very gruesome exceptions. "zünden" is found with photoflashes, rockets, explosives, fuel in an engine where a rapid, intense, short event is the consequence.